# Define `curry` in Lean Theorem Prover

Tags: theorem-proving, lean

I am reading [the official tutorial for Lean 3](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/index.html). I am stuck on the second exercise in [Chapter 2](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean/dependent_type_theory.html#exercises):

> complete the following definitions, which “curry” and “uncurry” a function.
>
> `def curry (α β γ : Type*) (f : α × β → γ) : α → β → γ := sorry`
>
> `def uncurry (α β γ : Type*) (f : α → β → γ) : α × β → γ := sorry`

My current attempt is

```
def curry (α β γ : Type*) (f : α × β → γ) (x : α) (y : β) : γ := f (x, y)
```

This is unsatisfying since I modified the type from the exercise rather than just replacing "sorry" with some code. What is a better approach to take while keeping the type the same? I'd appreciate some tips to point me in the right direction rather than a complete solution.

Comment: You can use `\lambda`-notation to write the term: `λ x y, f (x, y)`.

Comment: @jmc Now that you point it out, it is so obvious. I think part of the problem is that I've been reading sections gradually over an extended amount of time, so the stuff about lambdas isn't in my head immediately even though I'm familiar with the concept from other contexts (such as Haskell). Will you post that as an answer please?